# How to Store large data in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, large-data

I am new to MVC.I am having some doubts so please clarify me.

1. How to store large data in MVC4 and how to pass that data across the pages.
2. How to maintain user details across the pages.  In webforms we are having sessions but in mvc4 how we will do.
3. if we are having two actionresult of same name one will be fired on POSt action.  How the CLR identifies which Action method to be called..means how it will identify that POSt method is called.

Answer (score 4):

1. Define "large data" - remember that the web is stateless, persistence is done using a database or a server-side cache. I need more information about what you want to accomplish here.
2. ASP.NET MVC still supports Sessions. You can access the Session collection from any Controller action.
3. The Post action method must have a different method signature. The usual approach is to specify the view's model as a parameter, or a FormValueCollection, for example:

-

```
// GET
public ActionResult Foo() {
}

// POST
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(FooModel model) {
}

OR:

// POST
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(FormValueCollection postValues) {
}
```

Comment: if iam having large data (eg:list of 100 records)which i want to access in other pages.How can i accompliiish this.In webforms we will store the data in session and we can access where we want.But in mVC4 how to do this.There is an option called tempdata in mvc but it will work for 1 cycle.so how can we accomplish this.Please provide some code snippet so it would help full for me.

Comment: When you said large I thought you meant Millions Of records... Anyway you can still use Session[Key] as you did in web forms.